# find + grep + cp issue

Tags: linux, grep, find, cp

I've got some files in a directory and I would like to :

- Find those which are modified less than 1 day.
- In this result, find those that contain: "return code: -"
- In this result, find those that contain: "MNOR" or "TECH" or "FTAL"

I did it :

```
find /home/eleve/Bureau/test/ -mtime -1 | grep -lR "return code : -" |  grep -lR "MNOR\|TECH\|FTAL"
```

It work perfectly I've got my concerned files and now I would like to copy these files into another directory but I don't know how to do, I read a lot of things like "| xargs cp -t /directory" but it still doesn't work

Have you got a solution to help me ?

Thx you !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cp `find /home/eleve/Bureau/test/ -mtime -1 | grep -lR "return code : -" |  grep -lR "MNOR\|TECH\|FTAL"` Directory
```